# how to map files into an ipfs docker container

Tags: docker, ipfs

I have a docker container with ipfs running but I have an error adding files because the local file is not recognised. I wondered if anyone had any idea what could be the cause -

```
buntu@ip-172-31-39-89:~/.ipfs$ ll
total 76
drwxrwxr-x  8 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Oct 31 11:38 ./
drwxr-xr-x 11 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Oct 31 11:28 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu users     21 Oct 31 11:32 api
drwxr-xr-x 18 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Oct 31 11:32 blocks/
-rw-rw----  1 ubuntu ubuntu  4342 Oct 28 10:33 config
drwxr-xr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Oct 31 11:32 datastore/
-rw-------  1 ubuntu ubuntu   190 Oct 25 11:34 datastore_spec
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   299 Oct 30 15:28 docker-compose.yml
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Oct 30 15:45 ipfs-data/
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Oct 30 15:44 ipfs-staging/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Oct 30 15:26 ipfsdata/
drwx------  2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Oct 25 11:34 keystore/
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root       0 Oct 31 11:38 kkk
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu users      0 Oct 31 11:32 repo.lock
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    95 Oct 28 10:43 swarm.key
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu 10294 Oct 31 11:26 t
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    14 Oct 31 10:58 tet
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu     2 Oct 25 11:34 version
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-89:~/.ipfs$ sudo docker exec ipfs-node ipfs add tet
Error: lstat tet: no such file or directory
```

The mapping is done as follows -

```
sudo docker run -d --name ipfs-node \
  -v /tmp/ipfs-docker-staging:/export -v /home/ubuntu/.ipfs:/data/ipfs \
  -p 8080:8080 -p 4001:4001 -p 127.0.0.1:5001:5001 \
  jbenet/go-ipfs:latest
```

Comment: did you try `sudo docker exec ipfs-node ipfs add /data/ipfs/tet`?

Comment: that worked for this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to add files there, you have to make sure that they're present on the container.

When you execute `sudo docker exec ipfs-node ipfs add tet`, you're actually telling ipfs to add the tet file present in the container WORKDIR, independently from where you're executing the command. So, unless the file is actually present in `WORKDIR`, it won't be found.

In your case, you'll have to store the file in either `/tmp/ipfs-docker-staging` or `/home/ubuntu/.ipfs`, then you have to provide the path inside the docker container. e.g.

```sh
# for files stored in /home/ubuntu/.ipfs:
sudo docker exec ipfs-node ipfs add /data/ipfs/tet

# for files stored in /tmp/ipfs-docker-staging
sudo docker exec ipfs-node ipfs add /export/tet.new
```